# Update Magento Review form action for https

Tags: php, review, https

Within the review form on my store you can see:

```
action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>".
```

This generates a http link that breaks our secure page load.

My question is where is the getAction() function declared/built, and is it possible to update for compliance with https?

Comment: Note...I'd assume getAction() is a global function thus is it possible to edit it's function only for review's purposes?  I've been informed that this might require writing a custom module to handle only this process.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into how config.xml files function within Magento...

Create a new module:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-2.html

Then in your new module throw the following code in:

```
<secure_url>
    <review>/review</review>
</secure_url>
```

After that clear Magento Cache and your review form should now no longer conflict with https.